# Run some initialization code when Django (1.9) loads

Tags: python, django

I saw that from 1.7 there is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready, however this is per **each app**.

What I am looking for is a way to call some initialization code when **Django** is loaded, regardless of which apps it contains.
Many people suggest adding the code to wsgi.py, urls.py and settings.py, however all these methods are 'dirty'.

My scenario is that I have several apps that could be part of the Django deployment, and I would like any subset to have this init code.
I could write a *special* common app, but I assume there must be a Django way of providing init code.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Django, you generally have a project directory containing the global, app-independent files like `settings.py` and `wsgi.py`.  You can add global initialization code to `__init__.py` in that directory.

Be advised that this code is run very early (even before the settings are loaded), so some parts of the Django API are not available yet.

Comment: I guess that this method won't allow me to initialize some data structure from the DB, but possible from a file. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: @mibm You need to be more specific.  What kind of database initialization would you like to perform?  According to your question, the code is supposed to be independent of any app, so you can't access any models.  I wonder what you would like to do to the database without access to models.  If you ask about a specific use case, we will probably be able to help you.

Comment: Marmach - I was thinking of loading some data structure (a dictionary) from a file. Indeed, you are correct that if that data structure will reside in a DB I would need access to models ...